# How to listenTo to something outside of the referenced DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a library view which is referenced to a table in HTML like this:

```
//appview
var app = app || {};
app.LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#contacts',

//html
<table id="contacts" class="table table-striped">
<tr><td style="width: 20px;"><center><b>Id</b></center></td>
<td><b>Name</b></td>
<td><b>Surname</b></td>
<td><b>PhoneNb</b></td>
<td><b>Options</b></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What I'am trying to do now, is to add a few input fields and when user clicks the 'add' button, take data from them and create a new model. The only problem is, that because my DOM element is a table, i can't have those inputs inside it - it simply would make the whole look really messy. So i put those inputs outside of the table like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="contacts">
<tr><td style="width: 20px;"><center><b>Id</b></center></td>
<td><b>Imię</b></td>
<td><b>Nazwisko</b></td>
<td><b>Nr tel.</b></td>
<td><b>Opcje</b></td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="addContact"> 
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Kevin">
    <input type="text" id="Surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Smitt">
    <input type="text" id="PhoneNb" class="form-control" placeholder="51664354354.">
<input type="text" id="id" class="form-control" placeholder="5">
</div> 
<button id="add" class="btn">Dodaj kontakt</button>
</div>
```

On my previous project, i was referencing to the inputs inside my DOM element, so my view would look like this:

```
var app = app || {};
app.LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#books',
initialize: function( initialBooks ) {

this.collection = new app.Library( initialBooks );
this.render();
this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.renderBook );
},

events:{
'click #add':'addBook'
},

addBook: function( e ) {
e.preventDefault();
var formData = {};
$( '#addBook div' ).children( 'input' ).each( function( i, el ) {
if( $( el ).val() != '' ){
formData[ el.id ] = $( el ).val();
}
});

this.collection.add( new app.Book( formData ) );
},

// render library by rendering each book in its collection
render: function() {
this.collection.each(function( item ) {
this.renderBook( item );
}, this );
},
// render a book by creating a BookView and appending the
// element it renders to the library's element
renderBook: function( item ) {
var bookView = new app.BookView({
model: item
});
this.$el.append( bookView.render().el );
}
});
```

How i can change that code to be able to take data from the inputs, which are outside of the  referenced element in html? Should i create another view or is the other possibility?

Comment: Why not put the `<table>` and `#addContact` inside a common container and make that container your view's `el`? Trying to bind to things outside your `el` smells bad and should make you reconsider your design.

Comment: But my `app.view` generates a row for every model, which needs to be placed inside a table. If i did what u propose, the rows would be added at the end of the container `el` and not in the table. So unless there is a way to bind models to specific place inside the `el` (the table in my case) this is not  solution.

Comment: What's wrong with `this.$('table').append(...)` to add the `<tr>`s? No one is forcing you to use `this.$el.append(...)`.

Comment: that is exactly what i was looking for! I'am still new to all of this and i must have forgotten i can do this this way. Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a view for your form that has a reference to your collection. Something like:

```
app.ContactForm = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#addContact',
  events: {
    'click #add': 'addContact'
  },
  addContact: function(ev) {
    var formData = {};
    ev.preventDefault();
    this.$(':input').each(function() {
      if ( $.trim(this.value) !== '' ) {
        formData[this.id] = this.value;
      }
    });
    this.collection.add(new Contact(formData));
  }
});
```

then you'd just initialize both view with the common collection:

```
app.contactForm = new app.ContactForm({ collection: mycollection });
app.library = new app.LibraryView({ collection: mycollection });
```

And you can listen to the collection the same way as before.